# Let $G$ be a nonsolvable finite group, if $N_G(P)$ is solvable, show that G has a unique minimal normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a nonsolvable  finite group, if $N_G(P)$ is solvable for every nontrivial $P\subseteq G$ of prime power, show that G has a unique minimal normal subgroup H. And show  H is simple.

My understanding is that $G $ is non solvable with a solvable subgroup $N_G(P)$ and so G has a unique minimal subgroup $H$. And the  only normal subgroups of $H$ are identity. 
I don't know how to go by it any help will be appreciated. this is for learning purpose.

Comment: This is false as stated. Do you mean $N_G(P)$ is solvable for *every* nontrivial subgroup $P$ of prime power order?

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes for every nontrivial $P$ of prime power

Comment: Do you know any results about the structure of minimal normal subgroups of finite groups?

Comment: You can argue by contradiction: if there were two minimal normal subgroup, they would be disjoint. What does that mean for how they act on each other?